# Unresolved function or method in WebStorm 2017.2

Tags: webstorm

I am trying out WebStorm but am getting annoying errors regarding unresolved function or method for both Express and core node methods.

I have enabled the Node.js core library and invalidated cache/restarted.  Please see attached screenshot. Does anyone know how to make those incorrect error messages go away?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

works for me

[image]

Do you have **Node.js Core** library enabled in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM`? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/node-js-and-npm.html, *Code Assistance*

Comment: thanks, I had it enabled in settings but not preferences.